# Swift thread safe counter variable? used for tracking when to remove network activity indicator

Tags: ios, swift, thread-safety

Quick explanation of my scenario:

I have an iOS application than can perform lots of network calls simultaneously using different threads. In my iOS app I want to display the built in (on the status bar) network activity indicator when any network activity is taking place.

So what I done was start the activity indicator before any network call and then stop it once that network call has either errored or completed successfully.

What was happening (obviously) was that as soon as one network activity action had successfully (or errored) completed then it was removing the network activity indicator even though I knew other network activity was taking place.

So my solution was to create a static variable (as lots of classes perform networking activity) which keeps track of how many network requests are currently being performed (increments this static variable each time it starts and then decrements this static variable when they finish (either successfully or failed), only when this counter hits 0 then it turns off the network activity indicator.

This works fine, however now we get onto my question - lots of different threads are updating this static variable so my thinking is it needs to be thread safe?

What is the best method to do this - should I put each call to start/stop the activity indicator (which in turn increments/decrements the static variable) onto the main thread which then guarantees that this variable will be read/written too in serial?

Or I have been reading about using semaphores to tell a thread to wait if the variable is locked and then run when the other thread is finished with it on both the read and write of the variable?

Sorry for the long question but I wanted to give you the scenario of my current situation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of achieving this is serial queue usage.
You can use main queue `DispatchQueue.main.async { /* increment or decrement counter */ }` or `DispatchQueue.main.sync { /* increment or decrement counter */ }`

Or you can create new serial queue: `let counterQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "counter-queue")` and use it for the same purpose.

Comment: If using the main queue should it be sync or async? Does async just say that it can run at any time? Or that it can be paused half way through the function to allow something else to run? As if it can be paused then I guess I am no better off?

Comment: Sync will stop execution of current runloop and wait until block you pass into queue finishes execution. Async runs the code after the code in current scope finishes execution. Just don't call `DispatchQueue.main.sync` from main thread, because it will cause deadlock.

Comment: Ah I get it, cheers. Think I will just create a new queue to serialise these gets and sets. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Michael: Note that `UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible` must be set on the *main thread* (as all UI related stuff).

Comment: Hi @MartinR yeah as part of my method call for switching this activity indicator off I switch to the main thread to perform this one part, thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 4):

As [Sviatoslav Yakymiv said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44864539/1187415), a serial dispatch queue
can be used to synchronize the access to a counter which keeps the
current number of outstanding network requests.

One can use `DispatchQueue.main` for that purpose because `UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible` must only be
accessed on the main queue anyway.

On top of that, the management of the counter and the network indicator
can be encapsulated into a class in a
[RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization)-like manner:

```
final public class NetworkActivity {

    private static var count = 0

    public init() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if NetworkActivity.count == 0 {
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
            }
            NetworkActivity.count += 1
        }
    }

    deinit {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            NetworkActivity.count -= 1
            if NetworkActivity.count == 0 {
                UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Creating a `NetworkActivity` instance increases the global counter,
and the first instance makes the network indicator visible. 
Destroying the object decreases the counter, and the indicator is
hidden when the last instance is destroyed.

Example usage:

```
let request = URLRequest(...)
var activity: NetworkActivity? = NetworkActivity()
_ = activity // To suppress a "variable was written to, but never read" warning
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    activity = nil
    // ...

}
task.resume()
```

Comment: Also a nice solution!

Comment: thanks! This should be the correct answer since it actually solves the problem: `...used for tracking when to remove network activity indicator`